# Increment column data by comparing with columns from other table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a very complex calculation at hand and I am finding it difficult to get it through. Here it is. I have 3 table.

Table1: (ID1 and Sum are the columns of a table)

```
ID1    | Sum
123456 |  
345678 |
```

Table2: (City, ID2 are the columns of a table)

```
City |  ID2     
 NY  | 123456        
 CA  | 345678         
 TX  | 12345         
 BF  | 34567
```

Table3: (City, ID3 are the columns of a table)

```
City  |   ID3 
 LA   | 123456
 NB   | 12345
```

Final OUTPUT of Table1 should be as follows.

Depending on the values of Table2 and Table3, Table1 should look like this

```
 ID1   | Sum
123456 |   4
345678 |   2
```

I will explain the scenario first. i want to update the column 'Sum' of 'Table1'. This will be updated by comparing first 5 characters of column 'ID1' of 'Table1' with first 5 characters of column data present in 'ID2' column of 'Table2' and  'ID3' column of 'Table3'

for e.g. '12345' of Table1 (notice the actual value is '123456') is compared with column data of Table2 and Table3. Hence the sum comes out to be 4 in the final Table1

Input to the tables are in following form 
Table1 :- (Table2 and Table3 are in similar form of input)

```
[Object][Object]
[0-1]
  [0]: Object
      ID1: '123456'
      Sum:
  [1]: Object
      ID1: '345678'
      Sum:
```

---

Solution tried:

```
function count(key) {
return function (r, a) {
    r[a[key]] = (r[a[key]] || 0) + 1;
    return r;
};
}

Table1.forEach(function (a) {
a.Sum = this[a.ID1] || '-';
}, Table2.reduce(count('ID2'), Table3.reduce(count('ID3'), Object.create(null))));
```

The above solution compares the values of ID1 with ID2 and ID3 as it is. i want to use only first 5 characters of the data and then compare as mentioned above. Can someone let me know how my code needs to be edited to get my problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a better way than this... One options is

```js
var table1=[{id:'123456',sum:0},{id:'345678',sum:0},{id:'345',sum:0}];
var tables =  {"table2":[{id1:'12345'},{id1:'12345'},{id1:'1234567'},{id1:'345'},{id1:'34567'},{id1:'3'}],"table3":[{id1:'12345'},{id1:'12345'},{id1:'1234567'},{id1:'34567'},{id1:'3'}],"table4":[],"table5":null,"table6":"","table7":[{id1:'12345'},{id1:'12345'},{id1:'1234567'},{id1:'34567'},{id1:'3'}]};

//foreach key/value in the table1 object
_.each(table1, function(a, b) {
  var current = a.id;
  a.sum = 0;
    //foreach key/value in the tables 
  _.each(tables, function(c, d) {    
    //add check, expand this as required
    if (c != undefined && c instanceof Array) {
      a.sum += findTotal(c, current);
    }
  });
});

function findTotal(tableToWork, currentId) {
  var sum = _.countBy(tableToWork, function(e, f) {
    return e.id1.substring(0, 4) == currentId.substring(0, 4)
  });
  return sum.true == null ? 0 : sum.true;
}
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(table1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<p id="p">
  Hi
</p>
```

Let us know.

Comment: Hi, this is the solution if there is only 2 table. Wat if first table is updated based on other 2 tables?

Comment: @Rihana, i've updated the code based on your comment. but not sure i if it's what you asked.

Comment: @Searching-  this works. before i accept this answer now, i have one last question. What if one of the tables (table2 or table3 are undefined. and wat if both the table2 and table3 undefined. will the code still work in these cases ?

Comment: @Rihana extended the code based on your question. also updated the example, more close to your actual question.. I think..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one `aggTable` and an array `srcTables` of source tables and their associated id columns, a generic solution can be as follows:

```js
var aggTable = Table1;
var srcTables = [{ table: Table2, id: 'ID2' }, { table: Table3, id: 'ID3' }]; // can add as many as needed

// returns the key portion of the ID
function getKey(id) {
  return id.substring(0, 4);  
}

// count IDs inside one source table
function countIDs(table, id) {
   return _.countBy(table, function(row) { return getKey(row[id]); });
}

function aggregate(aggTable, srcTables) {
   // yields the following result: [{ 12345: 2, 34567: 2 }, { 12345: 2 }]
   var idCounts = _.map(srcTables, function(entry) { return countIDs(entry.table, entry.id) });

   // aggregate counts into the aggTable
   _.each(aggTable, function(row) {
     var id = getKey(row['ID1']);
     row['Sum'] = _.reduce(idCounts, function(memo, idCount) {
                      return (_.has(idCount, id)) ? memo + idCount[id] : memo;
                    }, 0);
   });
}
```